# Am I misusing didactic and tridactic?

Tags: phrases, terminology

I have often used *tridactic* to mean the process of the brain in hearing *pomme*, translating it to *apple*, and ultimately to the understanding of "apple."

*Didactic* I used loosely in conjunction with *tridactic* for the two-stepped process of just *apple* to the understanding of *apple*.

There must be a better word or phrase that distinguishes the difference between fluency and translation.

Comment: Have you looked up either of those in a dictionary? That should answer your question about both words.

Comment: I'd say you must by definition be misusing ***tridactic***, since by any normal definition of the word "word", *tridactic* ain't one. And the *di-* part of *didactic* has no connection to *di- = **two***, so etymologically the coinage is on shaky ground anyway. More crucially, *didactic* has no real connection with how brains interpret symbols, and in how many "steps" they do it.

Comment: Tridactic is most certainly a word.  Google it.  Here's one example: "This tridactic conversational approach to ‘meaning’ is necessary because all forms of communication are underdeterminate; that is, a listener or reader is needed to complete the communicative event."  And, didactic is not used as in "two," but rather used in reference to the nature of the one-way relationship between teacher and pupil.  I'm having trouble finding "ain't" in a dictionary.  But, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: [ain't](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ain%27t)

Comment: Most of the Google hits I get for 'tridactic' are either misspellings or misunderstandings of *triadic*, which actually is a word.

Comment: Yes, you're misusing them. 'tridactic' is not a word, and 'didactic' is 'about teaching. You will be terribly misunderstood if you continue to use those 'words' in the context of fluency and translation.

Comment: Dichotomy would be a better word to describe two different parts occupying the same space. In a physical object, take the Hagia Sophia to understand this concept. Inside this huge structure, you will find Christian symbols and influence along with muslim influence. Marilyn Manson said he chose his stage name because during the times of Marilyn Monroe and Charles Manson, the two would be considered complete opposites. So the name itself is a dichotomy.

Comment: I did google tridactic and the top hits are for this very question! It seems the only people who use the word are you and a small group (may be just one or two?) Christian evangelical writers. It's not a word, I'm afraid :-S

Answer (score 6):

OED does not have *tridactic,* so either it is not a word or it is so specialised and its occurrence so minimal that it does not merit inclusion.

*Didactic* means ***related to teaching,*** from the Greek *διδακτικ-ός* apt at teaching, from *διδάσκειν* to teach. While the *δι-* prefix may be related to *two,* it would refer to the bipartite relationship between teacher and pupil — it's difficult to see how that could be made into three.

You are using the words to mean "stages of understanding", which is to misuse *didactic* and consequently wrongly create the neologism *tridactic*. I would prefer the single step of understanding the word *apple* to have a *mono-* prefix and the two-step process involving translation to use *di-*; while I expect there are suitable words, I don't know what they are.

However, you are misusing *didactic* (and consequently *tridactic* as well).

Comment: The _δι-_ prefix is not related to two: it is simple reduplication (as is very often found in Greek when a monosyllabic verbal root is enlarged with the typical inchoative/frequentative suffix _-(σ)κ-_, just like in _γιγνόσκω_, for example).